# MySQL INNER JOIN Empty Rows with Subqueries and Max Date

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join, inner-join

I have 3 tables related by code, like this

[image]

I want to get the result of my 3 related tables by grouping the repeated rows according to update register dates. I have tried this to join them

```
SELECT
    stu.code,
    stu.name,
    stu.lastname,
    adr.address, 
    adr.phone,
    adr.register_date,
    uni.university,
    uni.degree,
    uni.register_date

FROM student stu

INNER JOIN 
    address adr
    ON adr.code = stu.code

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT code, MAX(register_date) reg_date
    FROM address
    GROUP BY code
) max_address
ON max_address.code = adr.code
AND max_address.reg_date = adr.register_date    

LEFT JOIN
    university uni
    ON uni.code = stu.code

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT code, MAX(register_date) reg_date
    FROM university
    GROUP BY code
) max_uni
ON max_uni.code = uni.code
AND max_uni.reg_date = uni.register_date
```

This code returns ...

[image]

I just want to return the rows with the max register date (Address and University tables) per student which would be the ones with the red arrows, How could I do this even if some students doesn't have a row in the university table ?

As you can see, it is happening with "Brandon Walker", there isn't an 854 code in university table and it is displaying the NULL in those fields but is not grouping by the Olivia's and John's records because I'm using `LEFT JOIN` in order to bring those "NULL" records from Brandon.

If I use `INNER JOIN` it won't retrieve the Brandon Walker register at all

```
INNER JOIN
    university uni
    ON uni.code = stu.code

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT code, MAX(register_date) reg_date
    FROM university
    GROUP BY code
) max_uni
ON max_uni.code = uni.code
AND max_uni.reg_date = uni.register_date
```

[image]

To be more specific I want to return this in my query

[image]

Any suggestion of how can I achieve this ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104). What happens if the register_date for more than one university is the same for a student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` isn't very helpful when you need to retain row-associations after finding the `MAX()` value for a particular student.

What logically comes to mind for me because the students table contains unique student codes, is to select the student data then perform subqueries on the `address` and `university` tables to isolate the single row with the latest `register_date` before LEFT JOINing (which will allow the attachment of `null` rows) to the `student` table.

SQL ([Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9fYsEVKXBtdWbhg5xZTASq/0))

```
SELECT
    a.code,
    a.name,
    a.lastname,
    b.address,
    b.phone,
    b.register_date AS addr_date,
    c.university,
    c.degree,
    c.register_date AS uni_date
FROM student a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT code, address, phone, register_date
  FROM address sub_b
  WHERE register_date = (
      SELECT MAX(register_date)
      FROM address
      WHERE code = sub_b.code
  )) b ON a.code = b.code
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT code, university, degree, register_date
  FROM university sub_c
  WHERE register_date = (
      SELECT MAX(register_date)
      FROM university
      WHERE code = sub_c.code
  )) c ON a.code = c.code
ORDER BY a.code
```

Output:

```
| code | name    | lastname | address | phone | addr_date           | university | degree | uni_date            |
| ---- | ------- | -------- | ------- | ----- | ------------------- | ---------- | ------ | ------------------- |
| 853  | John    | White    | craFtur | 315   | 2016-10-10 07:00:01 | Bristol    | 145    | 2011-02-19 00:00:00 |
| 854  | Brandon | Walker   | cra 101 | 313   | 2005-11-04 06:00:00 | NULL       | NULL   | NULL                |
| 855  | Olivia  | Wright   | cll 26D | 310   | 2012-05-06 07:00:00 | Stanford   | 10025  | 2010-01-07 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: @Fred It took me longer than necessary to post my solution for you because I had to manually type out the table schemas.  The images of schemas are better than nothing, but certainly not as helpful as having copiable schema **text**.  Even better is to ask your question and supply a preformed DB-Fiddle demo link.  This allows volunteers to instantly get to work on a proven solution.  You are sure to receive better, faster, and more support when you do so.  If my solution isn't perfect for your needs, I'm happy to adjust.

Comment: I know the comment section shouldnt be use to thank, but that was a very good answer, the next quesiton I will follow your suggestion about DB-Fiddle, thanks again.